# Android LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-layout

From the [reference link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) both the below two lines are doing the same.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

I don’t know which way is correct or proper. can some point out me what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, they are equivalent. `LayoutInflater.from(context)` is just a shortcut to the former, as you can see in the source:

```
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper to get the data from another class

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```